# Bulk remove category from custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, bulk

I know you can use bulk actions to add categories but how do you remove them in bulk?  I have a custom post type that is using a category (as status) and it needs to basically be toggled in bulk and frequently.  I thought just using a category for this would be a simple solution but I was frankly a little shocked when I learned you can only add categories in bulk but not remove.  This actually seems like something that would be included in the core.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a plugin? I found several that claim to do this just by searching for "bulk categories" in the WordPress Install Plugins page.

Comment: I did, and even tried a few but it seems most that I've seen or tried either aren't end user friendly or are horribly out of date and don't work.